# Split Testing and Regression To Mean

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Suppose we have news site where users can scroll through rows of links to stories. Success is measured by proportion of click thrus over total link impressions. We do a split test on changing the link color from blue to black. This test is done by randomly assigning a color to each link. The test is therefore run by selecting a random subset of users and then flipping coins for each link color they see (so they may see alternating colors).

I’m wondering if there’s a *safe* way of understanding the impact of color as a function of click thru rate decile. So for every user who was tested, take the click thru rate on blue links and use it to rank users by click thru decile. Then look at the lift of seeing a black link (by calculating the click thru rate for each user on black links). This would obviously be impacted by “regression to the mean” because ranking users would break randomness. Is there another way?

Comment: Are you saying you only do the cross over experiment if a participant clicks on a link to begin with?

Comment: @AdamO: not quite. We randomly select participants for the experiment. For each selected participate we randomly select a subset of links they see and switch the color. So they see a mix of both.

Comment: I can't see how regression to the mean would have anything to do with this. This seems like a simple ANOVA problem to me.